# GET_X_LPARAM never return negative value

Tags: windows

MSDN warned:

> Do not use the LOWORD or HIWORD macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and LOWORD and HIWORD treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities.

So I use GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_LPARAM instead, but I never get negative values in my multiple monitors environment, the values are always relative to the top-left corner of the window, how can I simulate to test negative values? My OS is Win 10 x64, could the behavior changed?

Comment: Which message are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get negative values on monitors that are to the left and/or above the primary monitor. This is only true for `WM_CONTEXTMENU` and the `WM_NC*` messages, most of the other non-NC mouse messages are relative to your windows client area, not the screen.